# Finished 1st Python project, for Mac, in PyCharm, PySImpleGUI and pyinstaller. Now need PC version. Know zero about Windows. Best path?

Tags: pycharm, pyinstaller, porting

Is there a clean way to directly convert finished Mac code to Windows?  Or must I get Windows versions of PYCharm, etc., bring the source across, tweak, and recompile?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understanding your question, but think you need a windows machine to create exe file.
Transfer your code and check if it runs.
[This link](https://youtu.be/jnUpSK3D3is) will help you with creating the exe